# Laravel route not defined while it is

Tags: php, laravel

When I want to enter one page I defined earlier, it just shows error. 
More specifically - `Route [/infos] not defined. (View: ...\resources\views\infos\create.blade.php)`.
In my `php artisan route:list`, it shows that the route exists normally. This post is my last hope, bc I'm trying to figure this out for a couple of days.

*web.php code block*

```
Route::get('/infos/{worker}/create', 'WorkerController@info')->name('infos.create');
```

*WorkerController code block*

```
public function info($id) 
{
    $worker = Worker::find($id);
    return view('infos.create')->withWorker($worker);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to call the route by that name inside the view? If you are trying to call `route('/infos')` then that is not valid, it would have to be `route('infos.create')`.

Comment: Yes. That's it. I just lost the concentration somewhere and lost in these minor syntax problems. Thank you. You can post the comment as an answer and I will mark it :)

Comment: That's ok, glad to help. Besides, there are already good answers to similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714675/laravel-5-route-not-defined-while-it-is