# Route [song.store] not defined

Tags: php, laravel

http://kristijanhusak.github.io/laravel-form-builder/overview/quick-start.html
Laravel form builder  Quick start

> Route [song.store] not defined.

I want to know how to write routing
This is my present

```
Route::resource('/songs', 'Account\Controller')
       ->except([ 'show']);
```

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough information, code and nothing else that could help us to understand what the real issue, could you please improve your question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 route not defined, while it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714675/laravel-5-route-not-defined-while-it-is)

Comment: @atymic it's a duplicate for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Your route is missing a name, you need to specify this so laravel can generate a URL for it.

```php
Route::resource('/songs', 'Account\Controller')
    ->except([ 'show'])
    ->name('song');
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `Route::group`'s in order to achieve the ability to prefix route names.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'song', 'as' => 'song.'], function() {
    // Route::get('example', function() { return; })->name('example');
});
```

In order to then access this route, you must use its name.

```
route('song.example');
```

Consider giving your route a name, this should fix the issue.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'song', 'as' => 'song.'], function() {
    Route::resource('songs', 'Account\Controller')
        ->except(['show'])
        ->name('songs');
});
```

Which can then be called like:

```
route('song.songs');
```