# How should I fix "Route [admin.conditions.update] not defined." error?

Tags: php, laravel

I can't fix this error: `Route *[admin.conditions.update]* not defined`.
I checked some other posts with the same question, but still can't figure it out.

I checked `php artisan route:list`. For `conditions.update` the path was :

```
admin/conditions/{condition} App/http/controllers/ConditionsController@update
```

The routes in `web.php`:

```
Route::group( ['prefix'=>'admin'] , function()
{
    Route::resource('/conditions','conditionsController');

    Route::get('index' , function() 
    {
        return View('admin.index');
    });
});
```

My `edit.blade.php` route:

```
{!! Form::model( $record , ['method'=>'PATCH' , 'route'=>['admin.conditions.update', $record->id] ] ) !!}
```

Error is:

```
Route [admin.conditions.update] not defined. (View: C:\wamp64\www\dbsystem\resources\views\admin\conditions\edit.blade.php)*
```

Some following errors:

```
in UrlGenerator.php line 304
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(InvalidArgumentException), 1)in PhpEngine.php line 44

at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\\wamp64\\www\\dbsystem\\storage\\framework\\views/e2e78c3d81e946fdb92174f035a7944bab024389.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'record' => object(ConditionsModel)))in CompilerEngine.php line 59

at CompilerEngine->get('C:\\wamp64\\www\\dbsystem\\resources\\views/admin/conditions/edit.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'record' => object(ConditionsModel)))in View.php line 137

at View->getContents()in View.php line 120
```

Comment: You can run `php artisan route:list` to see the routes you have defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 route not defined, while it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714675/laravel-5-route-not-defined-while-it-is)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your route name isn't working is because `prefix` only works for the url/uri. To prepend to the route names inside a group as well you need to provide an `as` to the group:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::resource('/conditions', 'conditionsController');

    Route::get('index', function () {
        return View('admin.index');
    });
});
```

Notice the `'as' => 'admin.'`. Don't forget the `.` on the end.

Comment: also my modals work only on one of my pages. can you help me solve that too?