# Laravel Route [admin.home.index] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This doesn't happen in my localhost and it only happens periodically and not a constant hit.

I have tried:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Clean all cache files on `bootstrap/cache/*`

I'm using Laravel 5.7, weird thing is it only happens sometimes and not all the time...

If i run php artisan `config:cache`, the whole site will be not usable, i'll need to run php artisan `config:clear` again to make it working again.

Artisan list:

All routes are there with their names etc.

My route file:

```
Route::namespace('Admin')->group(function () {

        Route::name('admin.logout')->get('/logout', 'LoginController@logout');

        Route::name('admin.home.index')->get('/', 'HomeController@index');

        Route::name('admin.user.index')->get('/user', 'UserController@index');
        Route::get('/user/dt', 'UserController@dt')->name('admin.user.dt');        
        Route::get('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@edit')->name('admin.user.edit');
        Route::post('/user/edit/{id}', 'UserController@update')->name('admin.user.update');                
        Route::post('/user/adjust/{id}', 'UserController@adjust')->name('admin.user.adjust');
        Route::get('/user/get/{username}', 'UserController@getUserByUsername')->name('admin.user.get');

        Route::get('/cron/remove', 'CronController@remove');
    });
```

Stack trace:

```
[2019-10-09 17:03:05] production.ERROR: Route [admin.home.index] not defined. (View: /var/www/html/admimsystem/resources/views/admin/layouts/default.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/admimsystem/resources/views/admin/layouts/default.blade.php) {"userId":780616,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Route [admin.home.index] not defined. (View: /var/www/html/admimsystem/resources/views/admin/layouts/default.blade.php) (View: /var/www/html/admimsystem/resources/views/admin/layouts/default.blade.php) at /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:374, ErrorException(code: 0): Route [admin.home.index] not defined. (View: /var/www/html/admimsystem/resources/views/admin/layouts/default.blade.php) at /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:374, InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Route [admin.home.index] not defined. at /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:374)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php(45): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->handleViewException(Object(ErrorException), 1)
#1 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/CompilerEngine.php(59): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\PhpEngine->evaluatePath('/var/www/html/y...', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(142): Illuminate\\View\\Engines\\CompilerEngine->get('/var/www/html/y...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(125): Illuminate\\View\\View->getContents()
#4 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/View.php(90): Illuminate\\View\\View->renderContents()
#5 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php(42): Illuminate\\View\\View->render()
#6 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php(202): Illuminate\\Http\\Response->setContent(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#7 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(747): Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response->__construct(Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#8 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(719): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router::toResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#9 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(679): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->prepareResponse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\View\\View))
#10 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 /var/www/html/admimsystem/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php(24): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(133): App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller->App\\Http\\Controllers\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 'admin')
#16 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(75): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/AuthenticateSession.php(39): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\AuthenticateSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#30 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(66): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#37 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 /var/www/html/admimsystem/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(681): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Show your route list `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 route not defined, while it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714675/laravel-5-route-not-defined-while-it-is)

Comment: This doesn't always happens, its randomly happens when i navigate to pages and will get error 500, after refreshing it works again.

Answer (score 2):

Add in your `web.php` file for the specific named route. [See named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#named-routes) define in laravel :

```
Route::get('your-url','YourController@yourfunction')->name('admin.home.index');
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to routes folder
2. look for web.php file
3. Edit the file with this code : `Route::get('customURL','YourController@defaultmethod')->name('admin.home.index');`
4. Save and see the changes
5. If it does not work, try to use these commands again 
   php artisan config:clear
   php artisan cache:clear

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to web.php
2. php artisan route:list
3. Check routes with controller
   https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing