# Route not defined in a href

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Route [paslon.create] not defined.

```
<a href="{{route('daftar.create')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">tambah1</a>
```

controller

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('daftar.create');
    }
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/create', function () { return view('/daftar/create'); });
```

my solution is changing in `<a href="/create" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mb-3">tambah1</a>`

and in web  `Route::get('/create', function () { return view('daftar.create'); });`

but I don't know if it will be safe or not

---

Comment: Please check your `routes/web.php` file for `paslon.create` or resource route associated with `paslon`.

Comment: this in my web.php ```Route::get('/create', function () {
    return view('/daftar/create');
});'''

Comment: `Route::get(...)->name('daftar.create')`, read [the manual](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes). if you want to do a resource controller, please do it [properly](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel says "Route not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28714675/laravel-says-route-not-defined)

Comment: Why are you not using your controller?
`Route::get('/create', 'Controller@create');`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling route with name and for that you have to define name first in the `routes/web.php`

```
Route::get('/create', function () { 
   return view('/daftar/create'); 
})->name('daftar.create');
```

For more better understanding checkout the documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing#named-routes

Answer (score 0):

By default your routes doesn't have any name, you can see it typing in console:

```
php artisan route:list
```

You will see route names.
You need to declare name yourself

```
Route::get('/create', function () { return view('/daftar/create'); })->name('daftar.create');
```