Middleware Laravel 11?
I want to define middleware in my Laravel project, this is my web.php file, when I try to check the auth, I get an error Route [login] not defined. Please help me define middleware in Laravel 11 in the resource controller and custom routes. By the way, I read everything in the laravel11 release notes, but I can't figure out how I can fix this. Should i create my custom middleware... Thanks... All Routes
Route::redirect('/', 'cars.index');

Route::middleware(['guest'])->group(function(){
    Route::get('/login', [UserController::class, 'showLoginForm'])
    ->name('user.showLoginForm');

    Route::post('/login', [UserController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('user.login');

});

Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])->group(function() {
    Route::resources([
        'cars' => CarController::class,
        'user' => UserController::class
    ]);
    Route::post('/logout', [UserController::class, 'logout'])->name('user.logout');
});

I tried everything, I read everything about Laravel 11 release notes, and i tried to create a static middleware method inside my controller, but everything failed. I don't really know how I can fix this... I am a beginner

Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28714974/16805423

login is a default route name that comes from Auth::routes(). Occasionally, you will find your application still redirecting to these routes.
My first idea would be to rename the route user.showLoginForm to login. You can also create a redirect from the login route to the user.showLoginForm route.

I FIXED IT!
The problem was my name on the login route, my name was user.showLoginForm, when I changed that to just login everything worked. Obviously Laravel auth is searching for the route named login and that is the problem. The middleware is now working. Thanks, everyone! 
Route::get('/login', [UserController::class, 'showLoginForm'])
    ->name('user.showLoginForm');

FIX!

Route::get('/login', [UserController::class, 'login'])
    ->name('login');



